# How to create a JSON object, send it to a Javascript and how to access it in the Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

My goal is to Prompt the user for a Location, and call my php program which will get that location's record from the database. Then send the JSON object back to the calling Javascript function which will then populate the user Form with the data from the database record.

I am stuck with figuring out the proper format to create the JSON and once received by the Javascript function, how to parse it properly to populate the user form.

Here is my Javascript function that should prompt the user, and call the php to retrieve the record from the database.

```
function partModify() {
    var WPN = prompt("Please enter the West Part Number", "Harry Potter");
    if (WPN != null) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    //            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;

                var frm = document.getElementById("form-ajax");
                var i;

    //          console.dir(response);      // for debug
        alert(this.responseText);
                for (i in this.responseText) {
                    if (i in frm.elements) {
                        frm.elements[i].value = this.responseText[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        xmlhttp.open("GET","part_get.php?q=" + WPN,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

}
```

Here is the PHP program that gets the database record and sends it back via JSON.

```
<?php

$q = ($_GET['q']);

// Build the query based on the passed in parameters

if(!empty($q)) {

    //The query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM part_data WHERE WestPartNumber = '$q'";
    //echo ($query); //see how our query look like at the moment

    $username="xxxx";
    $password="xxxx";
    $database="xxxx";
    $datahost="xxxx";
    mysql_connect($datahost,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

    $result=mysql_query($query);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $temp[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($temp);

    mysql_close();
    exit;
} else {
echo 'Empty call';
}
echo 'Exiting Call';
?>
```

The closest I have been able to get is that when I display the JSON object in my Javascript using the alert() call, i get the whole PHP file text along with the database record at the end.

Can someone help educate me on what I am doing wrong?

Rich

Comment: Your web server is treating the request as an html file to be fetched instead of a script to be executed. Delete the html.

Comment: I removed all of the HTML from my code above.

Comment: Tell us what you get when you call your php script directly from a browser. and then you show source code from browser (ctrl+u in chrome)

Comment: Now, I only receive the JSON which looks like the following:
[{"0":"36","PartID":"36","1":"Indiana","Location":"Indiana","2":"Fizer","Customer":"Fizer","3":"Caps","Family":  --and on to the end.
Does this look like a proper format?

Comment: I have updated my part_get.php file.  Changes are in the code above.
I cannot get the JSON format to have the Name:Value pairs.  Instead I get the following:
[["36","Indiana","Fizer","Caps","PC01","W-PC01","Fizer's Jar Caps","2","15","2","35 Ton","2","1","\u0000","\u0000","\u0000","\u0000","\u0000","\u0000","Mat PC23","","1.28","0","0","0.58","0","\u0000","","","0","0","0","0","0","\u0000","Custom","0","12","144","Production"]]

This is the correct data as expected from the query, but where are the name parts of the pairs?

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP Script is like an API, it should return only JSON.
So first thing to do is to call it from a browser http://localhost/part_get.php?q=99

Then view code source of the page (ctrl+u in google chrome) and check that you have a valid JSON string returned by your http server.

Also, you can get rid of all that messy JS code, and use JQuery then you'll have this:

```
$.getJSON("part_get.php", {
        q: WPN,
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
```

Comment: Hi, Kooli. If I change to JQuery, will I not need to go through all of my code and change all JS code to JQuery?  If so, I was hoping not to have to do all of that work. My project is pretty large.

Comment: @rtemen you don't need jquery. Pulling in a huge library just to make an slightly shorter ajax request is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You want to return the json_encode, not echo it. Echo essentially adds it to the HTML file. Return makes it available to the calling program.